# How to add small text in the center of a circled CSS without Adding padding property?

Tags: html, css, geometry

Hi i created a circle shape in CSS Using Border radius property.

Here i would like to add small text exactly in center of the circle without adding padding property because padding will increase the circle size.

How to achieve this, any idea?

Here is the Code:

```
#circle
{
width:100;
height:100;
border-radius:100%;
Background-color:black;
}
```

HTML

```
   <div id="circle">
      hi
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a text element vertically center by tweaking line-height property to same height as the element wrapper is, in your case #circle div line-height is set to 100px .

```
/* CSS*/
#circle
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:100%;
background-color:black;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
line-height:100px



}
```

Check out the implementation here
http://jsfiddle.net/FB64v/

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center;line-height:100px;` (where the line-height is equal to the desired div height).

Also, you should specify units for your CSS dimensions: instead of `width:100`, use `width:100px`.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work as desired if the text wraps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#circle {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}
```

I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qPqF/

**CSS**

```
#circle {
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:100%;
background-color:tomato;
}

#circle p {
text-align:center;
line-height:100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle"> <p> Google</p> </div>
```